# add diez tag after space using Jquery regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

I have a problem with replacing diez tag after space using regex. You can see the exact problem in this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/wdwpOv)**.

> 1-) First problem is when you press space then regext adding # but
>   after you continue the write something then problem will be come here *a
>   diez sign is added to each character*.
>
> 2-) Second problem is turkish characters i can not write `ü,ş,ı,ğ,ö`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("keyup", "#text", function() {
      $("#text").html($(this).text().replace(/\s{1,}/g, " #"));
   });
});
```

```css
.container {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:600px;
   overflow:hidden;
   padding:10px;
   margin:0px auto;
   margin-top:50px;
}
* {
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.addiez {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:30px;
   border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
   outline:none;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.addiez::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
   color: rgb(0, 0, 1);
}
.addiez[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before  {
      content:attr(placeholder);
      color: #444;
    }

.note {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:30px;
   font-weight:300;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   line-height:1.8rem;
   font-size:13px;
}
.ad_text {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   padding:10px 30px;
   overflow:hidden;
   font-weight:300;
   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   line-height:1.8rem;
   font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="addiez" contenteditable="true" id="text" placeholder="Write something with space"></div>
   <div class="ad_text" id="ad_text"></div>
   
   <div class="note">For example: When you write like: Hi bro how are you? Then jquery should change this text like this:
   #Hi #bro #how #are #you? I meant when user pressed space or pressed enter then add diez tag before the text like my exapmle.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turkish characters are not accepted because your event is triggered even when Shift or Ctrl is released. You'll have to manage this before.

By doing like this, you'll have to manage your caret, because every time a keyup event is triggered, the caret go to the begining and then you wrote countersize. This is du because of the reasignment of the text value.
You'll better use textarea and val().

But your function is not implemented to do what you want too: You are replacing every whitespace by hashtag. And I understand that you want every of your words prepend with hashtag?

The best I've done is that. But I still have problem with the regex as you can see:

```js
$("body").on("keyup", "#text", function (event) {
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape et enter
            if ($.inArray(keyCode, [46, 8, 27]) !== -1
                // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
                || (keyCode == 65 && (event.ctrlKey === true || event.metaKey === true))
                // Allow: Ctrl+Z, Command+Z
                || (keyCode == 90 && (event.ctrlKey === true || event.metaKey === true))
                // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
                || (keyCode >= 35 && keyCode <= 40)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }

            if ($.inArray(keyCode, [32, 9, 13]) !== -1) {
                var $textarea = $(this);
                var text = $textarea.val();
                text = text.replace(/(?!#)\S+/g, "#$&");

                $textarea.val(text);
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });
```

```css
.container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 50px auto 0;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .addiez {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #d8dbdf;
        outline: none;
        font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }

    .addiez::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
        color: rgb(0, 0, 1);
    }

    .addiez[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
        content: attr(placeholder);
        color: #444;
    }

    .note {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        line-height: 1.8rem;
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    .ad_text {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        line-height: 1.8rem;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <textarea class="addiez" id="text" placeholder="Write something with space"></textarea>
    <div class="ad_text" id="ad_text"></div>

    <div class="note">For example: When you write like: Hi bro how are you? Then jquery should change this text like
        this:
        #Hi #bro #how #are #you? I meant when user pressed space or pressed enter then add diez tag before the text like
        my exapmle.
    </div>
</div>
```